# Cylinder with top sized larger then bottom will not smooth side faces properly?

Tags: mesh, smooth

I have made a cylinder with the top sized up to match the diagram being worked with. This has run me into a problem now however because for some reason the smoothing is now leaving the edges slightly visible. When I place down an unedited cylinder the smoothing works just fine. Is there a way to stop that from happening so I get a constant smoothed surface? If not then how do I get the shape I'm looking for while maintaining a smooth surface? I thought it might just be fine but when I placed it in my game in its current shape the lighting showed the faces still. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: have you tried right click -> shade smooth and then turn on autosmooth in object data properties -> normals?

Comment: Yes. That is the process I used to smooth the mesh. Not sure why the faces still show through only when you size one face as done.

Comment: can you add a blend file? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) that usually works. If worse comes to worse you can always use a subsurf modifier

Comment: Just tried but its giving an internal error each time

Comment: I can send through a gdrive if allowed

Comment: weird.  anyway, I was suffering brain fade.  Of course changing the bottom radius makes the edges more visible.  You can either add more edges or use a subsurf modifier to get around this.  I don't need to see the file.